# From where can I download the latest Ubuntu portable on a USB stick?

Tags: downloads, portable

I want to download Ubuntu portable and I searched on Google and results came showing Ubuntu remix.I was not sure if it was genuine or not.
So please tell me.

Comment: For you, what is that thing that you call Ubuntu portable ?

Comment: Your question shows lack of research,  use simple Google search https://www.google.com/?q=ubuntu+on+usb+stick or put your question into the search. If you use Ubuntu, look into the usb-creator-gtk, it is accessible from dashboard too, it can create installer USB and also run as Live CD.

Comment: Download the iso from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/. Follow steps in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows to make a Live USB. When you boot from the live USB you can install it or just 'try' it.

Comment: This site is for *official Ubuntu distros* only, besides Portable Ubuntu Remix is discontinued 2011. But you can easily install Ubuntu to USB as portable OS if that is what you have in mind.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows users:

1. Download [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) .
2. Download Ubuntu ISO file [Ubuntu Desktop](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop).
3. Insert Flash USB.
4. Run Universal USB Installer and select Ubuntu from first drop down menu(Step .1)
5. Press Browse and select Ubuntu ISO downloaded file (Step .2)
6. Select Flash USB drive (Step .3) [Flash USB will be formatted and all data will be wiped]

[image: Universal USB Installer main window]

7. Press Create and wait to finish process (Step .4)

[image: Universal USB Installer last step]

8. Reboot your PC and select Flash USB to boot. (Pressing F12 or F2 and select Flash USB to boot)
9. Finish, You have a portable Ubuntu in you Flash USB.

Comment: -1 Why should I use Windows, when I can do the same with Linux/Ubuntu?

Comment: at least [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) (since it is cross-platform) will make more sense!

Comment: @A.B. to make Flash USB boot in Linux/Ubuntu he/she needs a Linux machine. It's chicken / egg issue.

Comment: I believe Rufus is the currently recommended installation tool. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: Download standard Ubuntu and the Ubuntu family flavours via http://releases.ubuntu.com/ . Use the following tools to create a live USB drive with Ubuntu: **Rufus** in Windows; the Ubuntu **Startup Disk Creator** in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and newer versions. **Disks** alias `gnome-disks` or **mkusb** in older Ubuntu and other linux distros; **Unetbootin** or `dd` in MacOS. Warning: `dd` is dangerous, so check and double-check. See this link and links from it for more details, http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389